Turning Slices into new separate TIFF documents in Photoshop
Sometimes when I scan photographic film, I scan the whole strip especially if the distinction between each frame isn't clear.

Or there is a contact sheet situation where images were scanned together.

I want to be able to create slices or selections around each image and have them open in a new document and edit them before I save them to file.
Right now I am either creating slices and going into Export for Web > PNG Save > All Slices but this is very long, there is a "Image exceeds the size Save for web was designed for" dialog I need to bypass each time, and usually results in the computer spinning beach balling, and creates a few more image slices than I asked for.
Another thing I've done is copying and pasting into a new document, but I sometimes lose track of what I've already copied and it's also a cumbersome process to repeat.
Is it possible to:
-select several areas in an image and have each area open into new documents?
or
-select several areas in an image and have the selected areas be saved as a lossless TIFF quickly?

Well slices is a bit of a legacy function in Photoshop. Meant for exporting PNGs as you say. It's a bit unclear what exactly you hope to achieve. You ask "Is it possible to open all of the slices into a new document in photoshop", but don't you mean "open each slice in their own separate document"?

Absolutely, I corrected the wording, hopefully the new wording makes more sense. I just want to select parts of 1 image and then have all of them open in new tabs without having to export first

You could create an action to copy, new doc, paste, save - Or new layer via copy (cmd/ctrl-j) to create a new layer for each selection. It's the selection part that's tricky. Slices can't be made into selections. So, I would think, at a minimum one would need to create a selection, then hit a shortcut to run an action. Or use the "user input" feature to allow a manual selection, then proceed. Either way, I think it at least will need to be a "watched" process to a degree.

Slices don't mean anything for any feature other than exporting. They are "floating" dimension records and they don't really see any pixel data. Slices are basically just a UI for a coordinates feature. You can't create selections from slices (which would make all you want so much easier), or actually perform any pixel operations with slices.

@Scott Yes, I would expect to create the selections by hand and then launch an action. Wouldn't saving the following action: "Copy > New doc > Paste" create a document always the same size based on the one used when the action was recorded?

New documents, by default, are the dimensions of what's on the clipboard. So if a selection changes, the document size would change.

Right this is why an action wouldn't work @Scott. Using slices the way I describe is a bit closer but slow

Here's an action that, given a selection, will prompt you for a filename and save a file containing your selection.

Make a selection.
In the Actions panel, click Create new set, click Create new action, enter a name and click Record.
Edit > Copy.
File > New.
Click OK. (Photoshop should automatically suggest the size of the clipboard contents and select the same color mode and profile as the mother document.)
Edit > Paste.
Layer > Flatten Image.
File > Save As.
Choose any destination for the file and click Save. (This is just a temporary file. You can delete the file after finishing the recording.)
File > Close.
In the Actions panel, click Stop playing/recording.
In the recorded action, click Toggle dialog on/off at the step where you Save.


With this method you would first systematically save each image of the sheet and then afterwards open all the images for editing. It's not hard to remember where you were because the previous selection will be visible.
The downside to this method is that you have to manually specify a filename for each image.

But in this solution if the images are different sizes the action will only create images of the same size that was recorded when making the action, correct?

No. The images get the size of the selection you have when running the script. So unique sizes if you want. Try it out. Doesn't take long to record

@MicroMachine, didn't it work?
